# When removing AMP pages, should they be redirected to normal pages?

Tags: google, redirects, amp

I have been told not to publish AMP pages anymore, that is was useless for the ranking on Google.

Furthermore, I noticed that sometines, people fall into my website from Google search on AMP pages whereas they are on computers with high screens!

Should I remove them and redirect them to normal pages which are anyway responsive?